# SQS sendMessage successful but message does not show up on the AWS console

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have a method that sends a message to a SQS Standard queue. The method returns a successful response upon execution. But the console does not show any messages in the queue. Any ideas on what could be the reason this is happening?? Can provide a code snippet if that is helpful. Thanks!

Visibility timeout has been set to 10 minutes.